Is the Lorentz-contracted length of an object its true length in the stationary frame?
Let's consider an iron rod, weighing $55.8\,\text{g}$ ($6\times 10^{23}\,\text{atoms}$) and having a cross section of $1 \,\text{cm}^2$. Its volume (one mole) is $7.1 \,\text{cm}^3$. Its proper length is obviously $7.1 \,\text{cm}$. At the speed of $0.8c$ ($\gamma=1.67$), its Lorentz-contracted length is $4.25 \,\text{cm}$. Using this number to calculate volume and then density, we arrive at the value of $13.1 \,\text{g}\,\text{cm}^{-3}$ (the same number of atoms confined to a smaller volume). Is this derivation correct? Does it imply the corresponding huge pressure? Or is the Lorentz contraction just about measurements, and not about physical objects themselves and their properties?

I stated in my answer that I might post an intuitive explanation of the submarine paradox. I have put together some notes that have become a bit of a treatise on the subject of relativistic density and buoyancy which I think will be very enlightening. Due to the size of my current answer and the size of my intended addition I was thinking of posting the treatise as a separate answer, but I fear I might be penalised for that. Any suggestions on how I should proceed??

@KDP - It is perfectly fine to ask a question with the intention of answering it yourself. See this on Meta.


Does it imply the corresponding huge pressure?

Nope. It does not. Pressure does not change with relative velocity. Consider a cubical container of gas that is at rest with respect to the observer, with equal pressure in all directions so the force per unit area is equal everywhere as depicted on left in the diagram below.

In a reference frame where the box is moving at 0.8c relative to the observer, the surfaces parallel to the motion are length contracted by a factor of $1/\gamma = 0.6$. Forces transverse to the motion are reduced by a factor of 0.6 according to the Lorentz transformation of forces, so the force per unit area or equivalently the pressure on the parallel surfaces are unchanged, because the reduction in force is exactly matched by the reduction in area. The areas of the surfaces transverse to the motion are not subject to length contraction and forces parallel to the motion are also invariant. This means the force per unit area or pressure on the transverse surfaces are unchanged. Therefore there is no change in pressure on any of the surfaces.

(The same number of atoms confined to a smaller volume). Is this
derivation correct?

The short answer is yes, the density does increase.
Density is defined as mass per unit volume and since the mass energy of an object increases and volume length contracts, the density of a moving body in SR must increase with relative motion. Care has to taken to note that this does not imply that a moving body turns into a black hole.

Is the Lorenz-contracted length of an object its true length in the
stationary frame?

The length contracted length of an object is its "true" length from the point of view of an observer that sees the object as moving. The rest length of a object as measured by an observer at rest with the object is called it proper length. Both measurements are equally valid from the point of view of the respective observers in their own rest frames. In every way we can measure, the length contracted length of an object moving relative to us has all the measurable physical consequences we would expect of an object that really is that shortened length.
I have just posted a question and self answer about the Submarine Paradox here that extends this answer. I hope it demonstrates that length contraction and density increase have real tangible measurable consequences.

Let me rewrite your calculations for clarity:
Mass of the rod: $M = 55.8 g$
Length of the rod: $L = 7.1 cm$
Cross sectional area of the rod: $A = 1 cm^2$
Volume in the rest frame: $V = L\times A = L = 7.1 cm^3$
Density in the rest frame: $\rho = \frac{M}{V} \approx 7.8 g/cm^3 $
Now, you boost along the length of the rod with speed $\beta = 0.8$ which gives you $\gamma=10/6\approx 1.67$.
Length in the boosted frame $L' = \frac{L}{\gamma} = \frac{7.1}{1.67} \approx 4.25 cm$.
Firstly, to get the energy density(or mass density which is the same in relativity) you need to calculate the frame dependent relativistic energy of the object which is not $M$ (the rest mass) but $\gamma M$ and thus the density of the rod in the boosted frame: $\rho' = \gamma^2 \rho \approx 19.9g/cm^3$, is higher than that in the rest frame, where one factor of $\gamma$ is from the relativistic energy and the other is from the length contraction. This density is the relativistic mass per unit observer-frame volume.
This is where we need to be cautious. Lorentz contraction is an effect that arises purely due to the relative motion between the observer and the moving object. But it has no consequence on actual pressure or density of the object in its rest frame. It is just that these measurements are frame dependent and spatial mass density is not a correct quantity to measure. You can only make sense of Lorentz invariant quantities. In the case of mass, $m = \sqrt{E^2-p^2}$, is a frame independent quantity but spatial volumes are not invariant themselves. Here, $m$ is the invariant mass of the object, $E$ is the energy of the object and $p$ is the $3-$momentum of the object.

As Miss Understands explains, length contraction is the result of a rotation in spacetime. In its rest frame, all parts of the rod exist simultaneously, but in any other frame through which the rod is moving, all those simultaneous instants are actually different times. Specifically, time towards one end of the rod is increasingly earlier than time towards the other end.
To see how this results in length contraction, you might like to consider a thought experiment, as follows. Imagine a train is passing a platform, along the entire length of which there are markers showing the distance along the platform. If you take synchronised photos of the front and rear of the train, then they will show you where the two ends of the train were at a given instant in your frame, and by looking at the distance markers on the edge of the platform you can figure out how long the train is. For example, the photo of the front of the train might show it at the 203 metre mark, and the photo at the rear might show it at the 85 metre mark, so you would conclude the train was 118 metres long. However, in the frame of the train, the two photos were not taken simultaneously- specifically, the photo at the rear was taken after the photo at the front, which means that the rear of the train had moved along the platform somewhat in the interval between the two pictures, giving the impression that the train was shorter than its true length.

The Lorentz contraction is just about measurements, and not about physical objects themselves and their properties, which must be measured in the rest system.

@timebeforespace Is correct, but lemme try to put it more succinctly.
The Lorentz transformation doesn't change the object at all. You're just rotating something in 4 dimensions and the SR SFX like length contraction and time dilation are optical illusions arising from the (imaginary) angle that it rotated.
They're both just ordinary foreshortening, exactly the same thing as the shadow of a rotating pencil hanging on a string.
The pencil doesn't suddenly get really dense when its shadow is the size of the pencil's eraser.
The ONLY difference between rotating a pencil so its shadow gets shorter and accelerating it to near c and watching it get shorter, is that in the latter case, the rotation angle is imaginary because you're rotating in the time dimension (for which distance is negative, relative to space).
As has been relevant here before, acceleration in n dimensions is always rotation in n+1 dimensions. Seen from the side, an object sitting on a rotating disk appears to accelerate left and right (in the x direction), But when seen from above in two dimensions, x and y. The object is seen to be rotating — that is, cyclicly trading momentum between two perpendicular directions. That's the definition of rotation that I use. I wonder if there's another word for it?
The interval metric equation says that elapsed time is imaginary length (specifically, it's the square root of -ct²). But its physical manifestation is negative distance. If you can see it that way (or at least treat it that way) it makes special relativity much, much easier.
Like,  it lets you see that given a triangle with sides extending into space and time (similar to Minkowski space), if you increase the length of the time side of the triangle, the hypotenuse gets shorter. Make the time side longer than the space side, and the hypotenuse length is negative.
None of this is surprising if you can just understand that it is not an analogy. Elapsed time really is negative distance. Seeing this as it really is makes many things become simple.

I would hesitate to call the Lorentz contraction an "optical illusion" because the way an observer gets to measure it, isn't by optically "looking" at the object but rather by positioning observers all along the length of the object, each one records via his own synchronous (in this frame) clock and assigned position the simultaneous positions of the ends of the object at a certain time. The issue of how relativistic effects affect what we optically perceive, e.g. Relativistic abberration is related albeit quite a different subject.

@Amit Sure, but if you take a picture of the shadow of a rotated pencil, the shadow still looks short even if you measure it very accurately. Those synchronized cameras are outside the inertial frame of the moving object. They're taking a picture of sometting that's already been rotated. It's just ordinary foreshortening, that's all. No big deal. It's just that the direction you're rotating into is time —  which is imaginary space. By accelerating, the object rotated out of real space and into imaginary space.

It's interesting that the Terrel rotation, which does describe the visual effect associated with an object moving at relativistic speeds, is indeed a combination of apparent spatial rotation and a contraction. So it's actually more "interesting" than just a foreshortening of the object along the direction of motion. See the very nice animation in the link to the Wikipedia page above...

@Amit What Wikipedia link? I'd like to watch it.

I've linked the text "Terrel rotation" in my comment above to the page. Here it is again just in case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation
